# update data on zoom event in chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm using **chart.js & React** in a project, I need to draw a chart of very large data, so I'm using sampling for ease of work and not using all available data.
but I want to update data when user zoom on chart for show them more precise chart.

Is there any way to **detect the zoom event** and **fetch the data again** for that part of chart ??

Comment: Chart js provides zoom plugin, please see the [Zoom Events](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/guide/options.html)

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can detect the zoom event in your chart component and trigger a data update accordingly. Chart.js provides options for event handling, including zoom events. You can set up an event listener for zoom events and fetch the necessary data for the zoomed-in portion of the chart.

```
   import React, {
        useEffect
    } from 'react';
    import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
    
    const MyReactChartComponent = () => {
        let chartInstance = null;
    
        useEffect(() => {
            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    
            // Initialize chart
            chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    ...
                }, // Initial data
                options: {
                    ...
                }, // Chart options
            });
    
            // Event listener for zoom
            chartInstance.canvas.addEventListener('wheel', handleZoom);
    
            return () => {
                // Clean up event listener
                chartInstance.canvas.removeEventListener('wheel', handleZoom);
            };
        }, []);
    
        const handleZoom = (event) => {
            if (event.deltaY > 0) {
                // Zooming in
                fetchDataForZoomedArea();
            }
        };
    
        const fetchDataForZoomedArea = () => {
            // Fetch more precise data based on the zoomed-in area
            // Update chart with the new data
        };
    
        return < canvas id = "myChart" / > ;
    };
    
    export default MyReactChartComponent;
```

Comment: thanks for your good answer but  do you know how to understand the user zoom area?
I mean for example user zoom in `x=1000 to x=1400` so I will fetch data for this area